# Regex to validate telephone number, must exclude leading zeros more than 1

Tags: regex

I have the following regex with which i am able to validate for telephone numbers against different types of numbers and it is working correctly (Landline + mobile).

```
(^[0][1-9]\d{8,}|^[+]\d{11,})(;ext=\d{1,})?$
```

To this I am trying to add one more condition to it, with leading zero taken into consideration.

- If the number does not begin with a zero, then the above regex is applied.
- If the number begins with a zero, and has more than 1 zeros in the beginning, then it should use the regex, but with only 1 zero in the beginning while discarding other leading zeros.
- Other zero's contained with the number are not an issue

**Example**:
Number - 0012345678901
With my current regex this fails as pattern is not matched. If i remove one zero in the start, pattern is valid (012345678901).

I have modified my regex to the following. Can I write this better?

> (^[0][1-9]\d{8,}|^[0][0][1-9]\d{8,}|^[+]\d{11,})(;ext=\d{1,})?$

Comment: ^[0]+[1-9]\d{8,}|^[+]\d{11,})(;ext=\d{1,})?$
add + to the first zero which means match one or more zeros

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Works as required

Comment: `(^[0]{1,2}[1-9]\d{8,}|^[+]\d{11,})(;ext=\d{1,})?$`, this pattern let just 1 or 2 at first of string